# Why do my ceiling fan lights flicker and then come on later?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

The lights on my living room ceiling fan do not come on when switched on. They flash on then off. But if you leave the switch on and come back a few mins later the light will turn right on. It’s been going on for a long time. The fan works just fine every time. House was a new build 2014. Not sure of brand the fan is.

Comment: What wattage and type of bulbs are in the fan?  Some "energy efficient" fans limit current to the light kit.

Comment: Yes, what bulbs are in there?

Comment: I’m not 100% sure. I know we have the same bulbs in the same ceiling fans in other rooms in the house with no issues.

Comment: We're more interested in if they are old style incandescents or LED.

Comment: They are long life incandescents but again they work in all other fan fixtures

Comment: Can anyone help with this